# 18.04 Install on Dell Power Edge 2950, LAN card not detected

Tags: system-installation

I am attempting to install 18.04 into a clean drive of a [Dell PowerEdge 2950](https://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/poweredge-2950/pd). Everything goes smoothly until it attempts to detect the network, where it fails every time.

i have used 16.04 and Win10 on this device in the past and it worked fine, and detected fine (as recent as this morning) but 18.04 refuses to detect network hardware....

Any ideas?

Comment: `sudo lshw -c network`, `sudo journalctl -b 0`, `sudo journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: so install with skipping network stuff and then run this after yes?

Comment: You can run the above commands from a LiveUSB or LiveDVD, or run them in 16.04. Copy the results, come back here, click [edit], and paste the results into your question. Please do not put them in Add Comments as that loses all formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Dell PC probably use Dual embedded Broadcom® NetXtreme II™ 5708 Gigabit2 Ethernet NIC.   As far as I can tell you can get a linux driver at this link:

https://www.dell.com/support/home/dk/da/dkbsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=29d9g

This is based on some googling and not from personal experience.